# How to find complete ebook details just from its ISBN?

Tags: isbn, search-engine

I know the title and the ISBN number of an ebook, but I do not know its exact edition.

Is there any official/unofficial site which keeps record of all the information corresponding to a particular ISBN?

Comment: This question does appear to be outside [the scope of what is on-topic](http://ebooks.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here. If you are able to modify the question to specifically address e-books, I would be happy to reopen it.